# Flutter Overlapped InkWells Gesture Detection

Tags: dart, flutter, gesture, detection

While working on an application, we have an instance where we want a card to have an inkwell as well as a button on the card (also with an inkwell).  However, I have been unable to determine a way to separate the gestures such that only the inkwell directly under the user's tap is invoked.  As it is today, it appears that the tap 'bleeds through' to the next inkwell such that both splash effects are invoked.  This is undesirable behavior, the application appears to be selecting the card not the invokable item on the card (note: actual application is much different but the same issue is present).  I have reproduced this in a simple application to demonstrate the bleed through when the user pressed the button in the bottom right of the card.  Is there something I am missing which can prevent this behavior?  Thanks

```
  class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: Card(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () { },
          child: Container(
            height: 150.0,
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              child: RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.red,
                onPressed: () { },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the normal expected `InkWell` behavior as most of the time you want to use it's tap feature for every widget in it's tree. So what you can do is to define a Stack and set the button in the z-axis absolute over the InkWell:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        body: Center(
        child: Card(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
                InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                        print("inkwell");
                    },
                    child: Container(
                        height: 150.0,
                    ),
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    onPressed: () {
                        print("button");
                    },
                ),
            ],
            ),
        ),
        ),
    );
}
```

If you would want to set the button in the bottom right corner again you can set a Row and Colum around it and assign it's alignment:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Container(
                height: 150.0,
                child: Card(
                color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[
                            InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                    print("inkwell");
                                },
                                child: Container(
                                    height: 150.0,
                                ),
                            ),
                            Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                    Column(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                        RaisedButton(
                                            color: Colors.red,
                                                onPressed: () {
                                                    print("button");
                                                },
                                            ),
                                        ],
                                    ),
                                ],
                            ),
                        ],
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

Upper code would result in seperated widgets:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write up this detailed explanation.  I had previously used a stack but had put the stack at a lower level in the widget tree.  This worked perfectly when I moved the stack to the upper level and positioned the widget on top of the card.